# Cannot Resolve third party libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I am using the Android canary 13(Bubble Bee). My problem is that I am unable to resolve any third part library. I have tried adding multiple different libraries but cannot resolve them during building project. When I sync the project after adding the library the project synced successfully by downloading the dependency but in the project that library cannot resolve and when I try to build the project it says as mention in the image [image]

Below is the code of of build.gradle(app) file.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ra.rightads"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}


dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
// Navigation dependencies
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10"
//Firebase dependencies
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.4"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
//Google material dependencies
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
// Picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
// Okhttp
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
//Viewpager
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
//Hilt dependency
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
//Multidex
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//Kapt
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
// sdp and ssp for dp and sp values
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
// Image Cropper
 // implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
}
```

Here is the code of my project level build.gradle file.Image cropper is the library I am currently trying to add.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    classpath('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3')

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I need help and I need to resolve this error. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at that project's page on GitHub, I see that it is no longer maintained. And since JCenter is shut down, you can't easily get the library using Maven/Gradle.

Someone has forked it and continues to develop it, so you can use [that library](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper) instead.

Replace `jcenter()` with `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` and replace `'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'` with `'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:3.3.5'`.